# Connect to WiFi when no Wireless Zero Config adapter is available

Tags: wifi, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, opennetcf

I've been using OpenNetCF SDF for years to connect to WiFi on an app I wrote.  My manufacturer has a new device that no longer has a wireless zero config adapter, so I'm forced to work around the issue.

I've searched for days on how to

1. Find nearby access points
2. configure a connection
3. connect to that connection

All without a WZC adapter.  I'm using .net CF 3.5 on a WM6.5 device.  I would prefer not to handle configuring this in the software, but I've found devices to be unreliable for maintaining access point settings, and my clients do not want their users configuring WiFi or in the OS at all.

I also tried to use the SDF WirelessNetworkInterface class, but I don't see how to configure an access point (name, security, pwd, etc).  I found this article, but the code has many compile issues I couldn't overcome.

I was using SDF 2.3, then got the latest from sourceforge yesterday - same issue on both.

I am looking for any solution. Preferably with SDF, but if there's something I can do in .Net 3.5, that would work as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to contact your manufacturer about there SDK for there security supplicant. SDF is only aware of the standard ZeroConfig supplicant.

It is not usual to have ZeroConfig active on industrial devices. No Warehouse wnats the popups etc for wireless hotspots. So they normally supply an alternative supplicant.

For example, Intermec by Honeywell offer there own SDK for the Odyssey Funk supplicant they use on there devices. But you can  switch this supplicant also to ZeroConfig.

If you state the manufacturer and model I can possibly help finding there SDK.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking the answer.  This is correct, and I was able to get the SDK from the manufacturer.